# xampp for Windows: How to choose absolute path?

Tags: windows, linux, xampp, absolute-path

I have my files in a linux hosting and the absolute path is `/home/kat/public_html/sites/kats`

Now I would like to know how to choose the absolute path of a web directory in xampp under Windows.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a XAMPP installation with default parameters your root directory should be located at:
"c:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\", so your website must be located at:
"c:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\kats"

The root directory can be changed in the "httpd.conf" apache's configuration file located by default at:
c:\Program Files\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
There is a variable called "DocumentRoot" with default value set to:
"C:/Program Files/xampp/htdocs"